# Shared clipboard won't work on virtualbox with ubuntu 17.10.1

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, clipboard

I have virtualbox on my HOST ubuntu 17.10.1 and also in my GUEST. I enabled bidirectional clipboard access, installed the guest additions (both from the CD and from the package manager), rebooted and I still don't have clipboard access.

I couldn´ t find anything about the ubuntu 17.10, only for older ubuntus, which also asked me to restart `VBoxClient`, but such service does not exist on my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try [this answer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031897/ubuntu-lxde-18-04-and-16-04-virtualbox-bidirectional-clipboard-sharing-not-worki) Specifically, after guest additions installed, open a terminal and type this:

```
sudo VBoxClient --clipboard
```

after that it should work even after reboot.